# How do I catch taps but not scrolling in Javascript in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, dom-events, touch-event

I'm making an Javascript web app and I can't for the life of me get the `touchstart` event to fire. I get the `touchmove` and `touchend` events no problem. This is a problem because as I see it the best way to distinguish between a tap and a scrolling motion is to zero a counter on the `touchstart` event, update it at `touchmove` and then compare it at `touchend`. I'm doing this so I can do some action at the end of tap but not a scroll. For instance, it would be very confusing if a page opened for an item in a listed after you finished scrolling down that list, but it would be nice to be able to tap on an item to open its page.

This is what I have:

```
// FIXME: this doesn't seem to ever fire
el.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  // make sure that at the start of every touch we're not considered to be moving
  alert("Touch starting");
  app.__touchMoving = 0;
}, false);

el.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
  app.__touchMoving++;
}, false);

el.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
  alert("Touch ended. We moved beforehand this many times: " + app.__touchMoving);
  // if we are moving
  if (app.__touchMoving > 0) {
    // stop, since we're dragging, not tapping
      return false;
  }
  // else we're no longer moving, so it was a tap
}
```

I never see the `touchstart` alert. If I scroll the `touchend` will fire and app__touchMoving will have some sort of decent value. On a side note, I've noticed that sometimes the `touchend` will seem to fire multiple times.

Am I missing something basic here? Plenty of people say that this should work just fine on Android (and iPhone) yet the first listener never seems to fire.

**Update:** I should mention that I've been testing on a Samsung Galaxy S running Android 2.1.

Comment: Your code works just fine on my Nexus One / CyanogenMod nightly (apart from a missing `)` at the end, and defining `el` and `app`). It detects touchstart, move and end, and correctly reports the number of "moves".

Comment: Great, *just* what I want to hear. ;-p I've been testing on a Galaxy S running 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if u can use it: [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll)